# Show the function sending $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ to $[\frac{z}{1}] \in \mathbb{Z'}$ is a bijection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The brackets around $\frac{z}{1}$ is just to emphasize that it is an element of the set $\mathbb{Z'}$, and not really a "fraction" as we naturally know it. So we are not allowed to use the direct fact that $z  = \frac{z}{1}$ to show this is a bijection. But we do have this definition: $[\frac{a}{b}] = [\frac{c}{d}]$ if and only if $a \cdot d = b \cdot c$ (this is regular multiplication).

So for such things like injectivity, we can show this by proving something like $[\frac{y}{1}] = [\frac{z}{1}] \implies y = z$. Since $[\frac{y}{1}] = [\frac{z}{1}]$ means $y \cdot 1 = 1 \cdot z$, we have $y = z$ so we have injectivity.

But for surjectivity, I am a bit stuck on what to use to prove that we can get all of $\mathbb{Z'}$.

Comment: What exactly is $\mathbb Z'$?

Comment: The set of all $[\frac{z}{1}]$ where the $z$ in $[\frac{z}{1}]$ is $z \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: So $\mathbb Z'=\left\{\left[\frac z 1\right]\colon z\in \mathbb Z\right\}$. Let $f$ be the given function and take an arbitrary $w\in \mathbb Z'$. Then, by definition, there exists $z\in \mathbb Z$ such that $w=\left[\frac z 1\right]$, i.e., such that $w=f(z)$. Basically the function is surjective by definition because its codomain is exactly its image.